# SQL Query not working on XAMPP PHP MyAdmin, but works on W3Schools Tryit

Tags: mysql

this is the query I am *attempting* to run

```
CREATE TABLE 'HDI' 
(
    'Center Name' varchar(255),
    'Incident ID' varchar(255),
    'Closed' varchar(255),
    'Description' varchar(255),
    'Completed' varchar(255),
    'Alert' varchar(255),
    'Q1' varchar(255),
    'Q2' varchar(255),
    'Q3' varchar(255),
    'Q4' varchar(255),
    'Q5' varchar(255),
    'Resolution' varchar(255),
    'Comments' varchar(255),
    'Contact Me' varchar(255)
);
```

I have attempted it without the single quotes on 'HDI' as well.

Running " 5.6.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)"

Comment: Get rid of the single quotes. Either use ticks or nothing.

Comment: use backticks '`' not quote character. i.e `Center Name` varchar(255),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes are used for text literals - not what you want., so remove them.

However some of your column names have spaces in them (not a good idea, but...), so these need to be delimited with backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE HDI (
    `Center Name` varchar(255),
    `Incident ID` varchar(255),
    Closed varchar(255),
    Description varchar(255),
    Completed varchar(255),
    Alert varchar(255),
    Q1 varchar(255),
    Q2 varchar(255),
    Q3 varchar(255),
    Q4 varchar(255),
    Q5 varchar(255),
    Resolution varchar(255),
    Comments varchar(255),
    `Contact Me` varchar(255)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of the quotes

```
CREATE TABLE HDI 
(
    Center Name varchar(255),
    Incident ID varchar(255),
    Closed varchar(255),
    Description varchar(255),
    Completed varchar(255),
    Alert varchar(255),
    Q1 varchar(255),
    Q2 varchar(255),
    Q3 varchar(255),
    Q4 varchar(255),
    Q5 varchar(255),
    Resolution varchar(255),
    Comments varchar(255),
    Contact Me varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: It was the quotes, but the quotes have been replaced with ticks (`)

Comment: need back ticks as column names contain spaces.